# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less

Tags: c#, string.format

ERROR: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

MVC app, trying to add items to my dropdown list but the error in the title keeps being thrown. What am I doing wrong?

```
 var maxLength = db.COMIS_tbl_VesselMaster.Max(x => x.Vessel_Name.Length);

foreach (table a in db.table)
{
    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();

    item.Text = string.Format("{0, -" + maxLength + "} => {1} - {2}", a.V + (a.I != null ? a.I : 0) + (a.G != null ? a.G : 0));
    item.Text = item.Text.Replace(" ", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;"));
    item.Value = a.VID.ToString();
    items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting negative maxLength into the string here:

```
        item.Text = string.Format("{0, -" + maxLength + "} => {1} - {2}", a.V + (a.I != null ? a.I : 0) + (a.G != null ? a.G : 0));
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by doing that, but it's the reason for your error.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified you'll be supplying `string.Format` with 3 arguments but you've only passed 1. The error is saying your tokens need to be between 0 and (number of passed arguments - 1).

```
item.Text = string.Format("{0, -" + maxLength + "} => {1} - {2}", a.V + (a.I != null ? a.I : 0) + (a.G != null ? a.G : 0));
```

Format string: `"{0, -" + maxLength + "} => {1} - {2}"`

Argument 0: `a.V + (a.I != null ? a.I : 0) + (a.G != null ? a.G : 0)`

Arguments 1 and 2 are missing.